# Space Invaders Killing Enemy using Bullet

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, shift

How can i make the enemyAI die when the bullet from the player hits the enemyAI ?
Here is what i have, i know its not Java but my programming language is based off Java.
I hope the code you guys suggest me isn't java command code.
I would want to have simple code.
Such as removing the enemyAI by shifting the array and detect the collision by the enemy and bullet positions.

In my current code i don't know how to make the bullet destory itself and the enemy when it collides with the enemy. I know how to detect the collision, like this:

```
if(bulletPosX[i] > enemyPosX[x] || bulletPosY[i] > enemyPosY[y]) {}
```

But i dont know how to delete them. I know i have to shift the array. But i dont know how to perform it in code.

```
import graphics;

int firedBullets = 0;
int maxBullets = 15;
int[] bulletPosX = new int [maxBullets];
int[] bulletPosY = new int [maxBullets];
int[] bulletDirX = new int [maxBullets];
int[] bulletDirY = new int [maxBullets];

int width = 10;
int height = 3;
int maxEnemy = 30;
int[] enemyPosX new int[maxEnemy];
int[] enemyPosY new int[maxEnemy];
int[] enemyDirX new int[maxEnemy];
int[] enemyDirY new int[maxEnemy];

void main() {
    // Information for Enemy
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + 1) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y = y + 1) {
            enemyPosX[] = x * width * 6;
            enemyPosY[] = y * height * 15;
            enemyDirX[] = 10;
            enemyDirY[] = 20;
        }
    }
}

void paintWindow() {
// Information for Bullet
    for(int i = 0; i < firedBullets; i = i + 1) {
        setColor(255, 255, 255);
        fillRect(bulletPosX[i], bulletPosY[i], 6, 30);
        bulletPosY[i] = bulletPosY[i] - 5;
        if(bulletPosY[i] < -50) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < firedBullets; j = j + 1) {
                bulletPosX[j - 1] = bulletPosX[j];
                bulletPosY[j - 1] = bulletPosY[j];
                bulletDirX[j - 1] = bulletDirX[j];
                bulletDirY[j - 1] = bulletDirY[j];
            }
            firedBullets = firedBullets - 1;

        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + 1) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y = y + 1) {
            for(int i = 0; i < firedBullets; i = i + 1) {
                if(bulletPosX[i] > enemyPosX[x] || bulletPosY[i] > enemyPosY[y]) {

                    // How can i delete the enemyAI ?

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void onKeyPressed(int code) {
    if(code == 37) {
        playerPosX = playerPosX - 15;
    }
    if(code == 39) {
        playerPosX = playerPosX + 15;
    }
    if(code == 32) {
        if(firedBullets < maxBullets) {
            bulletPosX[firedBullets] = playerPosX + 46;
            bulletPosY[firedBullets] = playerPosY - 30;
            bulletDirX[firedBullets] = 5;
            bulletDirY[firedBullets] = 5;

            firedBullets = firedBullets + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code you are using for collision detection will detect if the bullet is in a certain quadrant of the screen because you are testing for if the position of the bullet is to one side of the enemy, but have no limits to how far to one side is valid.

Secondly removing an element from an array and shifting all of the elements over one.

```
public void removeElement(int[] input, int index) {
    for (int i = index + 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i - 1] = input[i];
    }
    input[input.length - 1] = -1;
}
```

What this does is copy each of the elements after the index to the previous position overwriting the old value. then it sets the last element to -1, which you can change to any other desired value to mark null. This may not work in your language because of the .length which simply returns the length of the array.

Lastly, please don't tag language similar to java as java. tag it as what the language actually is.

Comment: This language doesnt support .length

Comment: How would you detect if the bullet has collided with the enemy ? And how would you remove the collided bullet and enemy ?

Comment: This language doesnt supoort null so i cant possibly do that

Comment: If you look carefully in my code , youre right that iy destroys itself when it reaches a certain point of the game field but i have also made a comment in the code where the enemy has collided with the bullet or when the bullet has collided with the enemy